# Puma Upstart not loading ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, upstart

I've deployed an app in production in an Ubuntu Server VM. It uses Puma, so I've followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

to configure it there (it is currently working properly on heroku, we are looking to migrate it to this new server).

This is my /etc/init/puma-manager.conf

```
# /etc/init/puma-manager.conf - manage a set of Pumas

description "Manages the set of puma processes"

# This starts upon bootup and stops on shutdown
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

# Set this to the number of Puma processes you want
# to run on this machine
env PUMA_CONF="/etc/puma.conf"
pre-start script
  for i in `cat $PUMA_CONF`; do
    app=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
    logger -t "puma-manager" "Starting $app"
    start puma app=$app
  done
end script
```

And my /etc/init/puma.conf

```
description "Puma Background Worker"

# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
stop on (stopping puma-manager or runlevel [06])

# change apps to match your deployment user if you want to use this as a less privileged user (recommended!)
setuid user
setgid user

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

instance ${app}

script

# source ENV variables manually as Upstart doesn't, eg:
. /etc/server-vars
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  # set HOME to the setuid user's home, there doesn't seem to be a better, portable way
  export HOME="$(eval echo ~$(id -un))"

  if [ -d "/usr/local/rbenv/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:$PATH"
  elif [ -d "$HOME/.rbenv/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
  elif [ -f  /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
  elif [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh ]; then
    source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
    if [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh ]; then
      source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
    fi
    # if you aren't using auto, set your version here
    # chruby 2.0.0
  fi

  cd $app
  logger -t puma "Starting server: $app"    
  exec bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
EOT
end script
```

It works properly BUT it is not setting the ENV variables I specify in:

/etc/server-vars

I don't want to put all ENV vars directly into this script because they are many, and it limits the usability of the script.

Comment: You should search for an upstart error log:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/36200/how-do-i-debug-upstart-scripts .
It may give you some insight on what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you have a Procfile?

Comment: You have the app path mentioned in `/etc/puma.conf`, right?

Comment: I've searched the logs and found some errors, it was due to that. But now I've encountered a new problem I describe on my post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use "set -a" before sourcing the environment file. Here's the documentation describing what set -a does: [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Try 'set -a' before sourcing your environment file as you can see in the following example:

```
# /etc/init/puma.conf - Puma config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Puma instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See puma-manager.conf for how to manage all Puma instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/puma.conf then manage puma with:
#   sudo start puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#   sudo stop puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#   sudo status puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service puma {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Puma Background Worker"

# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

# change apps to match your deployment user if you want to use this as a less privileged user (recommended!)
setuid deploy
setgid deploy

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

instance ${app}

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv/rvm
# quoted heredoc to tell /bin/sh not to interpret
# variables

# source ENV variables manually as Upstart doesn't, eg:
#. /etc/environment

exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  set -a
  . /etc/environment

  # set HOME to the setuid user's home, there doesn't seem to be a better, portable way
  export HOME="$(eval echo ~$(id -un))"

  if [ -d "/usr/local/rbenv/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:$PATH"
  elif [ -d "$HOME/.rbenv/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
  elif [ -f  /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
  elif [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh ]; then
    source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
    if [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh ]; then
      source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
    fi
    # if you aren't using auto, set your version here
    # chruby 2.0.0
  fi


  logger -t puma "Starting server: $app"
  cd $app
  exec bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/brilliant/config/puma.rb
EOT
end script
```